# What is close to $2^{\infty}$ in the 2-adic metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, p-adic-number-theory

What is close to $2^{\infty}$ in the 2-adic metric space?

If $2^{\infty}$ isn't defined, where would it seem most appropriate to put it, if it were defined?

I can see that 2-adics are equivalent modulo $2^{\infty}$ which would seem to imply it's at $0$.

Comment: Yes: formally it's $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^n=0$$

Comment: Is that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert2^n\rvert_2=0$, or what you put?

Comment: @Crostul ^^ or both?

Comment: @Crostul, it’s more than “formally” true, it’s True. And RobertFrost, it’s both.

Comment: @Lubin thanks these little insights are really useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^\infty = 0$

\begin{align*}
\Vert 2^1 - 0\Vert_2 &= \frac{1}{2}\\
\Vert 2^2 - 0\Vert_2 &= \frac{1}{4}\\
\Vert 2^n - 0\Vert_2 &= \frac{1}{2^n}\\
\end{align*}

Thus as $n$ grows $2^n$ approaches $0$, so it makes sense to define $2^\infty = 0$